# LIKE não funciona junto com BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql, select, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Algo de errado com esta consulta?

Está aparecendo todos os dados sem nenhuma filtragem. Mas quando eu tiro os `LIKEs` ela funciona ou se eu tiro os `BETWEEN` e deixo os `LIKEs` ela funciona. Uma só funciona sem a outra. Por que?

```
$produto = mysql_query("SELECT idProduto, tipoProduto, imagemProduto, marcaProduto, modeloProduto, conservacaoProduto, anoProduto, kmProduto, corProduto, portasProduto, transmissaoProduto, combustivelProduto, valorProduto, destaqueProduto, visivelProduto, opcionaisProduto, observacoesProduto, 'datacriacaoProduto', 'dataalteracaoProduto', usuariocriacaoProduto, usuarioalteracaoProduto FROM produto WHERE 
                                         (tipoProduto LIKE '%".$tipo."%') OR 
                                         (marcaProduto LIKE '%".$marca."%') OR  
                                         (modeloProduto LIKE '%".$modelo."%') OR  
                                         (conservacaoProduto LIKE '%".$conservacao."%') OR 
                                         (anoProduto BETWEEN '".$minano."' AND '".$maxano."') OR 
                                         (valorProduto BETWEEN '".$minpreco."' AND '".$maxpreco."') OR
                                         (kmProduto BETWEEN '".$minkm."' AND '".$maxkm."')")
```

Comment: Não deveria ser tudo `AND`? Com `OR`, quanto mais condições você coloca, mais resultados tende a receber. E cuidado, tem um problema de segurança no código, ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php

Comment: Já coloquei tudo como AND também e nada. Me parece que pode ser os parênteses, mas não sei a sequencia correta de como colocá-los, se for este o caso.

Comment: remove os parênteses

Answer (score 2):

Tem um problema estrutural na sua query.
Quando o valor de qualquer "like" vem vazio ele trás todas as opções, não importa se AND ou OR.Pois isso vai resultar num LIKE '%%' que literalmente trás tudo, não filtra nada.
Considere montar sua query dinamicamente só com os filtros que forem ser usados.
Por exemplo, jogando a query numa varável e ir montando:

```
if(trim(tipoProduto) != ''){
   $query .= 'AND (tipoProduto LIKE '%".$tipo."%') ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito pesquisar cheguei na solução abaixo. Acho q transformar as variáveis apenas em POST, tirar as aspas simples dos BETWEENs e colocar o formulario com enctype multipart, ele enfim funcionou. Acho q foi isso:

Comment: cade a solução?

Comment: Coloque a solução para que outros usuários possam ver.